# An strange operator in B(H)

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be a non-separable Hilbert space and $E$ be an orthonormal basis for $H$. 
Let $E_0$ be a countable  subset of $E$ and $\{\delta_i\}_1^{\infty}$ be a bounded sequence of $(0,\infty)$. For given an arbitrary sequence $\{h_i\}_1^{\infty}$ of unit vectors in $H$, I am looking for an operator $y$ in $B(H)$ satisfying in the following properties:

1- $\langle ye,f\rangle=0$ for all  $e,f$ in $E_0$.

2- $||yh_i||\geq\delta_i$ for every  $i\geq1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel the following argument works:

Let $E_0'$ be a countable subset of $E$ containing  $E_0$ such that $h_i's$  are all in the closure of span$E_0'$. Let $F$ be a countable subset of $E$ with $F\cap E_0'$ is empty. If $\delta=\sup \delta_i$, then the following operator works well 
$$y=M\sum_{f\in F,e\in E_0'}f\otimes e$$